# Where are files stored and read upon serialization?

Tags: java, serialization

Where does a file go upon serialization? Does it simply go in the folder where the jar file was run or is there some other place where it gets stored?

If its unclear what I'm referencing, consider the following code.

```
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileoutput = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.ser"));
        //Where does "test.ser" go in the computer?
        ObjectOutputStream objectoutput = new ObjectOutputStream(fileoutput);
        objectoutput.writeObject(randomobject);
        objectoutput.close();
        fileoutput.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you run that code? Where **does** the file go?

Comment: I goes wherever you specify (in case it is not specified the current location is used)

Comment: @ArjunNair This question has nothing to do with *Serialization*.

Comment: Where you are using serialization. Anyways, In Java this is solved by caching the serialized objects and writing the handle of it when it is written again.

See step 5 in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/output.html.

Comment: @KulbhushanSingh well said

Answer (score 1):

The .ser file is stored where ever you specify in the FileOutputStream.

For example

```
FileOutputStream fileOut =
         new FileOutputStream("/tmp/test.ser");
```

would store it in the tmp directory.

In your case, since no directory is specified, it's the working directory.